# SharePoint 2016 How to have users convert docx to PDF on a fly

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, pdf, conversion, docx

We are using SP 2016 with Word automation services enabled. I am able to convert word documents to PDF using the powershell commands. But, if I would want the users to convert on a fly, should we depend on a third party tool (Like Muhimbi)? Or the only solution is custom solution in SP 2016? I am not a developer and hence I am asking this. Using the PS commands I am able to give the url of the documents and convert them fine.

Any help is appreciated.

Vj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As with SharePoint 2010 and 2013, to use Word Automation Services will require you to develop a custom server-side (SSOM) solution. Muhimbi is another option which can either leverage WAS or it's own internal method of DOCX -> PDF conversion.

Comment: Thanks for the response Trevor.So if we are not using Muhimbi, then we need to use custom code to ha e this feature enabled right?More of a developer work?

Comment: That's correct. I created a solution for WAS years ago which I haven't had the time to maintain, but it'll give you an idea of what is required - https://github.com/Nauplius/WAS.